# Mean Value Property for Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in an open set $U$ and the closure of a disk $D(z_{0},r)$ is contained in $U$, then , $f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int^{2\pi}_{0} f(z_{0} + r e^{it})dt$, which is a version of the statement of the Mean Value Property for Holomorphic functions.

I understand that this is a restatement of The Cauchy Integral Formula for Disks.

How does one show that the MVP for Holomorphic functions holds for $Re(f) = u$ and $Im(f) = v$?

Comment: Take the real and imaginary parts of the integral expression of the MVT for $f$.

Comment: How do you define the integral of a complex-valued function? Write f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y), and then $u(z_0)+iv(z_0)=f(z_0)=\int_C f := \int_C u+ i(\int_C v)$ where $z=x+iy$, now equate the real part of RHS and LHS